# Double zero index in a foreach loop C#

Tags: c#, foreach

this is a very odd problem that I'm currently encountering.
I have a `Repeater` in my code in which i populate with data. This is working as intended.

On my repeater I got a OnItemDataBound like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" Visible="true" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="getOverlays">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <span><%#Eval("name") %></span>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My repeater displays the correct data, say that my datasource contains three names which should all be outputted in the span tag which it does! Up to this point everything is working fine.

Now comes the weird part. On my `getOverlays` function I have this code:

```
protected void getOverlays(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
  foreach (RepeaterItem item in repeater.Items) {
    Response.Write(item.ItemIndex);
  }
}
```

In my world, this void would write out

```
0
1
2
```

but now this line of code writes out

```
0
0
1
```

which for me is a big mystery! Have anyone encountered an issue like this before? What have i done wrong?

I clearly sees the 3 names of my datasource, and I **do** get three indexes just that the first two indexes gets the same index, which is 0.

Somewhat my index gets resetted after the first iteration or something, but I've never had this problem before, anyone got a solution for this or can point me in the right direction of why my indexes are distorted?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does the first code snippet output in the span? (The actual output)

Comment: Alfie; it outputs the correct value, this is why i am confused because everything is correct until I see the indexes in the OnItemDataBound.

Comment: The OnItemDataBound method get called for each item added to the repeater, and I believe it is before the item is added to the Items collection.  With three items it will be called three times.  The first time it is called the collection is empty.  The second time it is called it contains one item (index 0), The third time it is called it contains two items (index 0 and 1).  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not loop in OnItemDataBound event, it is automatically called once for every item. Instead you should use `e.Item.ItemIndex`. Probably the first time it is called, `Repeater.Items` has no items. The second time, there is one item (index = 0). And the third time, it has 2 items (indexes 0 and 1).

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, yes might have been that I haven't been working with Repeaters in a while and done most iteration over datasets manually. But yes, the issue resultet in that I did a foreach on an already foreached loop, thank you for clarifying. Peter B: Your post made me realize it, but thanks to James Dev aswell for pointing it out, both of you provided the correct answer. TYVM

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

OnItemDataBound is called after ***each*** item is data bound not when all of the data is bound. I think you are getting mistaken for what this event does.

So first loop no items, 0 after first item then 0,1 after. You will have to debug this to see what it is doing but this looks to be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

OnItemDataBound event gets fired for every item that is bound. So you should be doing the below instead

```
protected void getOverlays(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    Response.Write(e.Item.ItemIndex);
}
```